# Products problem with storeKit in swiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, skproduct

I've a problem with my store manager class. First I request the product from the server and then when the user select an option I run the payement process but I don't know why my products array is empty at the moment where I run the payement process...

My class code :

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    //FETCH PRODUCTS
    var request: SKProductsRequest!
    
    @Published var myProducts = [SKProduct]()
    
    func getProducts(productIDs: [String]) {
        print("Start requesting products ...")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Did receive response")
        var prodIndex = 0
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                    print(self.myProducts)
//HERE the array is completed with the 4 products
                   
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Request did fail: \(error)")
    }
    
    //HANDLE TRANSACTIONS
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    
    func purchaseProductString(identifier: String) {
        print(self.myProducts)
        // Send an empty array []...
            if let product = myProducts.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == identifier }) {
                let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
                print("NewPayement in progress")
            } else {
                print("User can't make payment.")
            }
        }

    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
            case .purchased:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .purchased
            case .restored:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
            case .failed, .deferred:
                print("Payment Queue Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error))")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .failed
            default:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func restoreProducts() {
        print("Restoring products ...")
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
}
```

And the code to active the payement process is :

```
 Button {
         storeManager.purchaseProductString(identifier: "FC_ABO_BASIC_MENSUEL")
        } label: {
              Text("TEST")
 }
```

Thanks for your help !